# Cocos2D: Box2D body that is movable by one type of object but not another

Tags: box2d, cocos2d

I'm in the process of creating a simple platform game using **Cocos2D 2.0** and **Box2D**. I'm trying to create a kind of crate object that cannot be moved by the player, but that *can* be moved by an elephant object. When the player runs up to the crate, it should stop him dead in his tracks (as if he is running into a static Box2D body). If the elephant runs into it it should get knocked out of the way (as if the elephant was running into a dynamic Box2D body of much smaller mass/density). I can't use collision bitmask because of course I want collision to occur in both cases, I just want that collision to result in different things depending on which type of object is hitting the crate.

Anyone have a hint as to how to make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Checkout pre-solve events: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15985/how-can-i-cancel-a-contact-in-a-b2contactlistener. Then you can decide how to respond to the contact based on the object doing to contact.

Comment: That _seems_ like the right way to address this, but I'm not looking to eliminate any contacts, I just want the physics to work differently depending on what is making contact with the blocks. There's undoubtedly a way to use PreSolve events to tackle this, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the rest of your logic, you could either use **collision filtering** to create a case where players ignore the box, but react to an invisible unmovable box, while elephants ignore the invisible box, but react to the visible box.

Or you could use **postSolvers**, using the contact object passed by postSolvers in this way:

```
if (contact.GetFixtureA().GetBody().itemType == 'player' && contact.GetFixtureB().GetBody().itemType == 'box' ) {
contact.GetFixtureB().GetBody().setMass(999);
}
```

That's an oversimplified javascript example, your implementation might be different, but  the concept is that you can manipulate the bodies referenced by the contact object passed to the postSolver you set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As far as I can tell, this actually can't be solved by categoryBits and maskBits. As I mentioned above "I can't use collision bitmask because of course I want collision to occur in both cases, I just want that collision to result in different things depending on which type of object is hitting the crate." In other words, I'm not looking to eliminate any contacts, I just want the physics to work differently depending on what is making contact with the blocks.

Comment: Sorry for the bad answer ;), I just edited it, hinting two possible approaches.

Comment: Cool, thanks! The invisible box trick worked well. I have two bodies: one static and one dynamic. I used collision filtering so that the elephant knocks against the dynamic and the player against the static. The static body's position is updated as part of the standard update() loop to have the same position as that of the dynamic body.